# sentencia sql muestra valores duplicados al insert en mysql

Tags: php, array

soy nuevo en programación php.
Estoy desarrollando un programa que lee de un vector en base datos y le adiciona nuevos valores.
Esta es la definición de la columna en BD:

```
art_anyact_margen   varchar(255)    utf8_unicode_ci     Sí  NULL
```

Este es el tratamiento del php:
-> la sentencia sql de lectura de la factura me devuelve el codigo de articulo, fecha y cantidad:
--> leo factura: 113250 albaran :119899articulo :CR57507080Año :23 Mes : 04 Indice: 3 Fecha : 2023-04-28 cantidad: 8
--> como el articulo no existe, recorro el vector inicializando a 0.
--> adiciono la cantidad al vector ($w_indice es el mes)
`$w_array_anyact_cantidad[$w_indice] = $w_array_anyact_cantidad[$w_indice] + $fac_cantidad;`
--> reviso el array antes de preparar el insert:
--> cantidad calculada despues en el vector año 23

```
array(12) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(0) [2]=> int(0) [3]=> int(8) [4]=> int(0) [5]=> int(0) [6]=> int(0) [7]=> int(0) [8]=> int(0) [9]=> int(0) [10]=> int(0) [11]=> int(0) }
```

--> la cantidad 8 esta correctamente asignada al es 4
-->preparo el array para guardarlo:

```
$array_anyact_cantidad=implode(',', $w_array_anyact_cantidad);
```

--> este es el insert

```
INSERT INTO t_articulos (art_codigo, art_descripcion, art_familia, art_anyact_fac_bruta, art_anyact_dto_articulo, art_anyact_dto_comercial, art_anyact_bonificacion, art_anyact_dtos, art_anyact_base_com, art_anyact_prontopago, art_anyact_fac_neta, art_anyact_coste, art_anyact_comision, art_anyact_margen, art_anyact_cantidad, art_anypast_fac_bruta, art_anypast_dto_articulo, art_anypast_dto_comercial, art_anypast_bonificacion, art_anypast_dtos, art_anypast_base_com, art_anypast_prontopago, art_anypast_fac_neta, art_anypast_coste, art_anypast_comision, art_anypast_margen, art_anypast_cantidad ) VALUES ('CR57507080','MONOMANDO LAVABO FRONTAL CENTURY','A575' ,'0,0,0,425.28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0' ,'0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0' ,'0,0,0,1159.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0' ,'0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0' ,'0,0,0,1159.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0' ,'0,0,0,1416.8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0' ,'0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0' ,'0,0,0,1416.8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0' ,'0,0,0,425.28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0' ,'0,0,0,0.14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0' ,'0,0,0,991.38,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0' ,'0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'
```

--> este último vector corresponde a la cantidad.
--> busco esta fila en la tabla y el valor de cantidad en el vector es el doble:

```
SELECT art_codigo, art_anyact_cantidad FROM `t_articulos` WHERE art_codigo ='CR57507080';
```

Codigo Articulo art_anyact_cantidad
CR57507080      0,0,0,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
--> he repasado el codigo 100 veces y no veo el fallo,
Agradezco ayuda. Saludos.